# In R's randomForest package, do factors have to be explicitly labeled as factors?

Tags: r, statistics, random-forest, factors

Or will the package realize that they are not continuous and treat them as factors? I know that, for classification, the feature being classified does need to be a factor. But what about predictive features? I've run it on a couple of toy datasets, and I get slightly different results depending on whether categorical features are numeric or factors, but the algorithm is random, so I do not know if the difference in my results are meaningful.

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to test a script or function that uses the random number generator (RNG) in a reproducible way, try setting the seed for RNG with `set.seed(number)`, where `number` is any integer, before running the function. Then you can test if your hypothesis is correct or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a difference between the two. If you want to use a factor variable you should specify it as such and not leave it as a numeric.

For categorical data ([this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49243/rs-randomforest-can-not-handle-more-than-32-levels-what-is-workaround) is actually a very good answer on CrossValidated):

> A split on a factor with N levels is actually a selection of one of the (2^N)−2 possible combinations. So, the algorithm will check all the possible combinations and choose the one that produces the better split

---

For numerical data (as seen [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76590/how-to-choose-the-split-in-random-forest-for-categorical-predictors-features)):

> Numerical predictors are sorted then for every value Gini impurity or entropy is calculated and a threshold is chosen which gives the best split.

---

So yeah it makes a difference whether you will add it as a factor or as a numeric variable. How much of a difference depends on the actual data.

Comment: it does indeed depend on the data at hand, like you say. i have used `randomForest` package on genomic data (so all predictors were in {0, 1}) and passing them as continuous or categorical made no difference. in the former case splits were with conditions like `x > 0.5` or `x < 0.5` which amounted to a binary choice between 0 and 1. however, inexplicably, RF is much slower with categorical predictors, so if i can, i always opt out for continuous attributes.